# Python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python

```py
def readFile(CHARACTERS_FILE):
    try:
        charactersFile = open(CHARACTERS_FILE, "r")
        lines = charactersFile.readlines()
        buffer = [lines]
        charactersFile.close
    except:
        print("An error occured.")

    for index in range(len(buffer)):
        buffer[index] = buffer[index].rstrip('\n')

    print(buffer)

    return buffer
```

Always returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

I'm having no luck stripping these newlines. Help??

Comment: `buffer` is a list-of-lists.  You can't call rstrip() on a list, exactly as the error says.

Comment: You also don't call `.close()` on the file. You put the attribute but you don't actually close it.

Comment: Why did you do `buffer = [lines]`?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue you have is that you're nesting your `lines` list inside a new one-element list `buffer`. That seems unnecessary, and it's causing your exception when you try to access the strings but get a list instead.

Try either:

```
buffer = charactersFile.readlines()  # if you don't need lines at all
```

or:

```
lines = charactersFile.readlines()
buffer = list(lines)                 # if you want buffer to be a shallow copy of lines
```

Answer (score -1):

`buffer = [lines]` remove the brackets to `buffer = lines`.
This way it's not a list anymore and you can perform your string operation. I had my struggle with this kind of errors too.

Here's some code you can try

```
buffer = [] # to create the list
# no need for close later. for good practice use 'with'
with open(CHARACTERS_FILE, "r") as file: 
    lines = file.readlines()
for x in lines: # x will be each str of your lines.list
    buffer.append(x) # and like this you add them to buffer
    # the string operation you planed later 
    # could be done before appending though but try it yourself
```

Comment: I could cry, both that it was something so simple, and out of appreciation. Thank you!